# Why is GetShortestDayName returning a shorter name than expected?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetShortestDayName(DayOfWeek)` is supposed to return names like `Su`, `Mo`, etc. as shown in the output of the example on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getshortestdayname).

Instead, I get only one letter: `S`, `M`, etc.

Code to reproduce: (I'm using WPF .Net 6)

```
DateTimeFormatInfo en_us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
string s = en_us.GetShortestDayName(DayOfWeek.Tuesday);
```

This is not useful to me since Tuesday and Thursday for example, have the same identifier. What could cause this issue, so that I can fix it and get the expected `Su`, `Mo`, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely "by design" as outcome of switching from Windows-specific way of getting globalization information to publicly available data.

Following article [Breaking change: Globalization APIs use ICU libraries on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api) explain the change (but indeed does not go into specifics like "if short names are changed"):

> Starting in .NET 5, if an app is running on Windows 10 May 2019 Update or later, .NET libraries use ICU globalization APIs, by default.

And the [ICU site](https://icu.unicode.org/home) lists abbreviations as one of the components (highlighting is mine):

> Formatting: Format numbers, dates, times and currency amounts according the conventions of a chosen locale. This includes translating month and day names into the selected language, **choosing appropriate abbreviations**, ordering fields correctly, etc. This data also comes from the Common Locale Data Repository.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the following setting to your (`.csproj`) project file to not use the [ICU globalization APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that were introduced in .NET 5:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a change from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET Core 6 (possibly all versions of .NET Core - I can't confirm right now).

In .NET 4.7.2 I get two-character results; in .NET 6 I get one-character results.

I also don't see any documentation online that indicates that the change was an intentional breaking change.

I would submit a bug ticket to either update the documentation (and admit that it was a breaking change) or revert the behavior.

A workaround would be to take the first two characters of `GetAbbreviatedDayName`.

Comment: Thanks. (+1). I think [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71772589/why-is-getshortestdayname-returning-a-shorter-name-than-expected#comment126837410_71772589) found it - Globalization was changed as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api).

Comment: Yep. That explains it. Still might be worth a bug report if nothing else but to change the documentation.